# Rhino Mocks help needed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

`enter code here`I have following method where i need to write unit test case to test this method.

```
    public void ProcessDormantApplications()
    {
        List<long> dormantApplicationIDs = new List<long>();

        dormantApplicationIDs = service.GetDormantApplications();

        if (dormantApplicationIDs.Count > 0)
        {

            foreach (long dormantID in dormantApplicationIDs)
            {
                string msg = service.UpdateDormantApplications(dormantID);
             }
            }

           }
       }
```

and this is the TEST method i wrote.

```
[TestClass]
public class DormantApplicationsTest
{

    ILogger logger;
    IService Service;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        logger = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ILogger>();
        Service = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IService>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TESTProcessDormantApplications()
    {
        ////arrange
        ////act
        var target = new BLogic(service, logger);
        target.ProcessDormantApplications();

        ////assert
       // service.AssertWasCalled(x => x.
    }
}
```

The actual method calls another service layer which inturn invokes web service to get data. In this scenario I am not sure what to `ASSERT` in this situation.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void CheckProcessDormantApplications_InBetweenApplicationFailedToUpdate()
    {
        ////arrange
        var applicationIds = new List<long>()
        {
            1,2,3

        };
        UpdateResponse.isSuccess = true;
        UpdateResponse.errorMessage = string.Empty;

        Service.Stub(x => x.GetDormantApplications()).Return(applicationIds);
        for(int i=0; i <= applicationIds.Count-1; i++)
        {
            if (i == 1) //set this application id response to FALSE so it should continnue with next record as well
            {
                UpdateResponse.isSuccess = false;
                UpdateResponse.errorMessage = "making it fail for test";
            }

            Service.Stub(x =>x.UpdateDormantApplications(applicationIds[i])).Return(UpdateResponse);
        }
        ////act
        var target = new BLogic(Service, logger);
        target.ProcessDormantApplications();

        ////assert
        foreach (long id in applicationIds)
        {
            Service.AssertWasCalled(x => x.UpdateDormantApplications(id));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you provide you have to set a behavior on `GetDormantApplications` which return some ids, then verify that `UpdateDormantApplications` was called for each id:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Check_ProcessDormantApplications()
{
    ////arrange
    var applicationId = new List<long>()
    {
        //put here some ids
    };

    DormantServiceAdapter.Stub(x => x.GetDormantApplications()).Return(applicationId);
    var target = new DormantApplicationsBusinessLogic(DormantServiceAdapter, logger);

    ////act        
    target.ProcessDormantApplications();

    ////assert
    foreach (var id in applicationId)
    {
        DormantServiceAdapter.AssertWasCalled(x => x.UpdateDormantApplications(id));
    }
}
```

Comment: so, you mean we are mocking what GetDormantApplciations() method should return and then call updatedormantapplciations for each id? if so then how are we going to test tru getdormantapplciations method which actually should return a list of ids?

Comment: @user3264937 you don't, It's `UT`, you should verify only the behavior of the unit under test(`ProcessDormantApplications`). In a different`UT` you should verify the behavior of `GetDormantApplications`...

Comment: Thanks for the clarity; one question though, aren't we executing [calling real method] updatedormantqapplications when we say DormantServiceAdapter.AssertWasCalled(x => x.UpdateDormantApplications(id))?

Comment: okay after debugging with your code kind of understood why stub needed for get dormant applications and how those are being used. But still dont undestand what is the purpose of DormantServiceAdapter.AssertWasCalled(x => x.UpdateDormantApplications(id)) this line? is it ensure test case validating for each application id updatedormantapplications is called? so that we can say all code is covered?

Comment: @user3264937 yes the line `DormantServiceAdapter.AssertWasCalled(x => x.UpdateDormantApplications(id))` verifies that the method `UpdateDormantApplications` was called with a specific id. In your case you have to do it foreach id.

Comment: Perfect Old Fox; marked as answered. but one doubt, i wanted to test 3 application ids where inbtween application failed bvut it should continnue to the next id without eixting. But, i wront the test case [added in original question] where the UpdateResponse.IsSuccess set to false for all 3 records though I made my stub to set differently. can u pls state the reason?

Comment: well, figured out, i had to instantiate UpdateStatus object each time for a applciation so that its tied to each record with changes. finally tests are running:)